# How to set a resource in Visual Studio to "Embedded"? Persistence is greyed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, fody-costura

I want to build a single executable file(exe) of a program I wrote, but this uses an unmanaged library from a third party. Costura.Fody allows to embed unmanaged libraries by adding them to a `costura32` or `costura64` folder and then as an embedded resource, but when I try to do the latter following [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2c9s1d7(v=vs.100).aspx), the resource persistence is set to Linked and I cannot change it. The article also points out that file resources are always linked.

So how should I add the third-party DLL as an embedded resource?